# Append not working in jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, lightbox

I'm trying to append `tp-lightboxactitem` into `tp-lightboxcontainer`. Can any one help me with this thing. It's not working, I want that lightbox activeitem comes inside `tp-lightboxcontainer` and `tp-lightboxactitem` comes in center of it .

```
$('body').append('<div id="tp-lightboxcontainer" class="'+opt.style+' lightboxitem"></div>');
        var tp-lightboxcontainer=find('#tp-lightboxcontainer');
        tp-lightboxcontainer.append('<div id="tp-lightboxactitem" class="'+opt.style+' lightboxitem"></div>');
```

Comment: Your code won't even run because it's syntactically wrong, it's not jquery append. `var tp-lightboxcontainer` should be something like `var tp_lightboxcontainer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<div id="tp-lightboxcontainer" class="'+opt.style+' lightboxitem"></div>')
    .appendTo('body')
    .append('<div id="tp-lightboxactitem" class="'+opt.style+' lightboxitem"></div>');
```

You're really only working with one object here, so you can do this in one line. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qmMRC/)

1. Make the container (target container)
2. Append it to the `<body>` (still target container)
3. Append your item to the container (still target container)

ps: if you want to use that container for more things, feel free to cache it too by putting `var whatever =` in front of it.

Comment: can u tell me when the tp-lightboxcontainer is not taking any css changes

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Code is syntactically not correct as Esailija said. I have working and correct code below:
Changes done:

1. opt need to be defined properly before.
2. variable name should not have '-', but can have '_' instead as Esailija said before.
3. Find operation was wrongly done in that code.

> ```
> var opt=""; 
>
> // op can be whatever defined before in the code.
> $('body').append('<div id="tp-lightboxcontainer" class="myClass" lightboxitem"></div>');
>
> //Find updated.
>
> var tp_lightboxcontainer=$("body").find('#tplightboxcontainer');  
>
> tp_lightboxcontainer.append('<div id="tp-lightboxactitem" class="'+opt.style+' lightboxitem"></div>');
> ```